# Converting dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the xlsx file where data are like this:

```
4,citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I want to seperate each item into next column, so the cells will be like this:
`A2 contains 4, B2 contains citrus, C2 contains fruit` and so one.

How do I make it?

Comment: `df['colname'].str.split(',', expand=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use read_csv(). I'm not sure I works directly with a.xlsx file, but you can try. Else maybe you can convert the file in.csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Another solution can be to use read_excel() and Split the column

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel(filename)
df['columnname'].str.split(pat=",", expand=True)
```

Comment: I checked the columns names with df.columns, and I got this: Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'). I put df[0].str.split(',', expand=True) and I saved into the csv, but didn't work.

Comment: When I print with print(df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)) it shows fine, but after assigning df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True) and saving it gives me the same result as before.